# Посоветуйте либу на java  для построения 3d поверхностей

Tags: java, 3d

Кто занимался чем-то подобным - поделитесь опытом, посоветуйте библиотеку.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, [lwjgl](http://www.lwjgl.org/)

Answer (score 2):

А чем не устраивает стандартный API [Java 3D](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html)?